# Provide File name and hit Save button grammatically in Firefox printing

Tags: c#, pdf.js

How to programmatically provide a **File name** and then hit **Save** button in Firefox print dialog box using asp.net.

The link https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html where Print button is clicked and I want to either avoid the Save Print Output As dialog or give Filename and hit Save button programmatically. Is it possible?

[image]